# How do you obtain the transaction uuid after submitting an invoke transaction using the nodejs HFC

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger

Im using the hyperledger HFC to send requests to the blockchain . How can I obtain the uuid of a transaction after submitting an invoke transaction using the sdk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results returned via the 'submitted' event contains the uuid of the transaction.   See below for an example.

```
var tx = user.invoke(req);
tx.on('submitted', function (results) {
    console.log("uuid=%s", results.uuid);
});
```